# URL rewriting and URL redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

So I have the following rule in my htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^post/ post.php [L]
```

This gives me access to `localhost/blog/post.php` via `localhost/blog/post/`

Now, when I'm directly typing `localhost/blog/post.php` it does not redirect me to `localhost/blog/post/`

Is there a way to redirect to `localhost/blog/post/` in .htaccess or should I do that in php code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an additional rule to redirect /post.php to /post

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/
#1)--redirect /post.php to /post--#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /post\.php
RewriteRule ^ /blog/post/ [NC,L,R]
#2)--rewrite /post to /post.php--#
RewriteRule ^post/ post.php [L]
```

Comment: This works ! Can you please explain how the redirect part work ?

Comment: @Younes The first part of the code redirects the browser from **/post.php** to **/post/** while the second part then rewrites the **/post/** back to its orignal location, it happens internally and the browser stays on /post

Comment: And this avoids redirection loops as `THE_REQUEST` only ever contains information about the *original* request - it never changes.